# Get Trigger times for SQL Jobs from MSDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

I have a to make a document on all the SQL Jobs in out DB servers with the trigger times, is there a way of getting all the trigger times from **msdb**, without going to every job under SQL server agent and checking the properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
select 
    j.job_id,
    j.name,
    s1.next_run_date,
    s1.next_run_time,
    s2.*
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
left outer join msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules s1
    on j.job_id=s1.job_id
left outer join msdb.dbo.sysschedules s2
        on s1.schedule_id=s2.schedule_id
```